# ¿El pools es un dispositivo virtual?

Tags: pool

Actualmente por hobby estoy adentrandome en los servidores NAS, pero aun tengo una confusion con este par de palabras.
Pools - volumen virtual - dispositivo virtual
Son lo mismo? uno funciona a traves del otro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma de analogía

Pool : Un terreno que tienes
Dispositivo: Una bodega, casa, rancho, edificio construidos sobre el terreno
Volumen: Un cuarto o división dentro de cada bodega, casa, edificio.

El pool ofrece acceso lógico a tus *espacios de almacenamiento*. Los dispositivos son latas, aparatos físicos. Los volúmenes son definiciones lógicas que pueden abarcar incluso más de un dispositivo.